# SQL SERVER 2012 - Getting report about columns optimisation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, report

I have a script that gaves me report about tables in database.

My question is how to get also a data about the most unoptimised columns?

Example:
the column name, reserveddata, useddata, unoptimised/unusedspace.

The code:

```
use tempdatabase

create table #getdatav1 (
    [table] varchar(255),
    [rows] int,
    reserved varchar(255),
    data varchar(255),
    index_size varchar(255),
    unused varchar(255))
create table #getdatav2 (
    [servername] varchar(50),
    [basename] varchar(50),
    [table] varchar(255),
    [rows] int,
    reservedKb int,
    dataKb int,
    reservedIndexSize int,
    reservedUnused int)

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="insert into #getdatav1
EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"
insert into #getdatav2 ([servername], [basename], [table], [rows], reservedKb, dataKb, reservedIndexSize, reservedUnused)
select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), [table], [rows], 
SUBSTRING(reserved, 0, LEN(reserved)-2), 
SUBSTRING(data, 0, LEN(data)-2), 
SUBSTRING(index_size, 0, LEN(index_size)-2), 
SUBSTRING(unused, 0, LEN(unused)-2)
from #getdatav1

select * from #getdatav2
order by reservedKb desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`sp_spaceused` only works in the context of a table and cannot be run for individual columns if that is what you're looking for.

You could cursor through each column in the table(s) you wish to examine and copy each column individually to a temporary table which would then only contain that column, which you could then run `sp_spaceused` on to get your results on a per-column basis.

Check [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1480959.aspx) for an example of a stored procedure which demonstrates the concept of copying an individual column to a separate table and then running `sp_spaceused` on it. You could take this as a staring point, then just create cursor(s) to step through each table and field you wish to analyse, calling your `sp_spaceused2` stored procedure (although I would suggest choosing a better, more descriptive name for this!) for each one and `INSERT`ing the results back to a table for final display.